# How does a tiling of the hyperbolic plane look on the hyperboloid model?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, tiling

> How does a tiling of the hyperbolic plane look on the hyperboloid model?

For example this tiling:

[image]

My understanding is this is how a hyperboloid looks like if viewed from the origin, or something like that. is there a tool where one can view (a truncated) hyperboloid surface that is tiled. For example, would the tiles on the sides still look circular if viewed from a normal angle? I am assuming not, but i wouldnt have assumed a conical slice to be elliptical either.

Comment: That picture is using the Poincaré model, which is actually the hyperboloid seen from the point $(0, 0, -1)$. You can [transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami%E2%80%93Klein_model#/media/File:Relation5models.png) that picture from the Poincaré model to the Klein model, and the from the Klein model to the hyperboloid model by the mapping $\displaystyle (x,y)\to\frac{(x, y, 1)}{\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}}$, or you can just transform the picture in the Poincaré model directly to the hyperboloid.

Comment: Otherwise, you can se a hint of what a tiling can look like in the hyperboloid model either [here](https://www.roguetemple.com/z/hyper/models.php) under "Minkowski hyperboloid" or [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/291808218_Creation_of_Hyperbolic_Ornaments_-_Algorithmic_and_Interactive_Methods) at page 20.